# NgRx with Reactive Forms Patch Value

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to patch a value from a subscribe method.

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.store.pipe(select(fromUsuario.getUsuario))
      .subscribe((res) => {
        this.formUsuario.patchValue({
          nome: res.nome,  <-------------- Line 36
          telefone_celular: res.telefone_celular,
          telefone_fixo: res.telefone_fixo
        });
      })
  }
```

This works very well when i come from a page to another, because the state is already there.

But, when i open direct on the url component, i am receiving an error:

```
core.js:5845 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nome' of null
    at SafeSubscriber._next (perfil.component.ts:36)
```

How i can do this async at component? thanks for any answer.

Comment: just surround patchValue with an if condition. if(res && res.nome){}

Comment: @Ikkyy are you trying to set default values for those fields based on the user you get from your selector?

Comment: Yes i am, the aswner from @ng-suhas worked.

Comment: a good idea would be to use ngx-sub-form https://github.com/cloudnc/ngx-sub-form#first-component-level and the RootFormComponent where you'd just pass your data once they're ready using the async pipe

Answer (score 0):

`if(res && res.nome){}`

did the job.

The help was from the comment of @ng-suhas